# search with upper and lower case letters

Tags: c#

I want to make a search in a datagrid with the text "Modele" but it takes only the upper case or lower case according to the text to search. i want that it show me the "Modele" regardless of upper or lower case.[image]

This is what i try:

```
  private void textBox_model_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string searchValue = textBox_model.Text;

    for (int u = 0; u < dataGridView_Articles.RowCount; u++)
    {
        if (dataGridView_Articles.Rows[u].Cells[5].Value.ToString().Contains(searchValue))
        {
            dataGridView_Articles.Rows[u].Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridView_Articles.Rows[u].Visible = false;
        }
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change this:

```
string searchValue = textBox_model.Text;
```

to this:

```
string searchValue = textBox_model.Text.ToLower();
```

Comment: Seems rather inefficient.

Comment: And incorrect in some locales: https://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/05/turkish-i-problem-and-why-you-should-care.aspx/